# How to use static html file in flask?

Tags: html, css, flask, thickbox

I'm trying to use `thickbox` with register page. While just opening `index.html` with one line like this:

```
<a href="register.html"  class="thickbox" >Register</a>
```

the register page will display successfully

But On the server,

```
<a href=" {{ url_for('static', filename="register.html") }} "  class="thickbox"></a>
```

the page will not appear.

I've already put `register.html` under the file `static` and the route is right

If I don't add `class="thickbox"`, the register page will appear. so the route is right.

---

Comment: By default `{{ url_for('static', filename="register.html") }}` will transformed to `/static/register.html`.

Comment: You have a space before the `{{` in your `href`.  `<a href=" {{` should be `<a href="{{`